# Delete calling destructor but not deleting object?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, destructor

So I have been working with c++ and pointers for a year and a half now, and i thought i had them succeed. I have called delete on objects many times before and the objects actually got deleted, or at least i thought they did.

The code below is just confusing the hell out of me:

```
#include <iostream>

class MyClass
{
public:
    int a;

    MyClass() : a(10) {
        std::cout << "constructor ran\n";
    }

    void method(std::string input_) {
        std::cout << param_ << "\n";
    }

    ~MyClass() {
        std::cout << "destructor ran\n";
    }

};

int main()
{

   MyClass* ptr = new MyClass;

   ptr->method("1");

   delete ptr;

   ptr->method("2.5");

}
```

this code outputs:

```
constructor ran
1
destructor ran
2.5
```

I was confused as to why it was not throwing an error of any sort - I was expecting a memory out of bounds exception or alike, but nothing. The `for` loop was in there incase there was some sort of hidden garbage collection, even though as far as I know there is no garbage collection in c++.

Can anyone explain as to why this code works, or where I am going wrong with this code for it not to give me the error?

Comment: It works entirely by accident. It's an error to use a pointer after you've `delete`d it. It may do what you think is the right thing; it may not.

Comment: Using a pointer after `delete` enters you into Undefined Behavior territory.

Comment: You might want to set the pointer to the `nullptr` value after deleting it, to see your expected behavior.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're misunderstanding what `delete` does. All `delete` does is call the destructor, and tell the allocator that that memory is free. It doesn't change the actual pointer. Anything beyond that is undefined.

In this case, it does nothing to the actual data pointed to. That pointer points to the same data it pointed to before, and calling methods on it works just fine. However, this behavior is not guaranteed; in fact, it's explicitly unspecified. `delete` could zero out the data; or the allocator could allocate that same memory for something else, or the compiler could just refuse to compile this.

C++ allows you to do many unsafe things, in the interest of performance. This is one of them. If you want to avoid this kind of mistake, it's a good idea to do:

```
delete ptr;
ptr = NULL;
```

to ensure that you don't try to reuse the pointer, and will crash immediately if you do rather than having undefined behavior.

Comment: "*calling methods on it works just fine*" Not accurate, there is a truckload of cases where it wouldn't "work just fine". The whole point, as others have mentioned, is that UB is allowed to do *anything* including appearing to work.

Comment: @syam I mean it works fine in the case that he's demonstrating, not that it's a fine thing to do. I've expanded my answer to clarify. I tend to find that explaining what's actually happening (the runtime is simply leaving the data alone, and when you call the method it operates just as it would before the delete) is more helpful than just saying that it's undefined behavior and anything could happen (though the latter is technically correct).

Comment: @syam I've added further explanation to clarify that the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Well the problem with explaining *what happens* is indeed that it's not universally correct: on another implementation it might not do the same. Hence my nitpicking. ;) Another compiler might order a pizza or format your hard drive and it would still conform to the standard (but you already know that, I'm mostly commenting for the benefit of OP).

Comment: @syam I mean what is actually happening on his system. There is a specific behavior that's happening, and it's good to explain what is actually going on. While you should be aware that the spec leaves it undefined, in the real world, the actual behavior of systems can be important.

Comment: I generally do set my pointers to null/0 when they are done with, but i was always under the impression that freed memory cannot be referenced by the application again unless it is re-allocated, and would throw an error if i tried. I guess that thought was just a by-product of learning pointers and hitting that memory out of bounds error over and over.

Comment: @Gunshin Yeah, there are some errors that are caught, such as trying to access null pointers (or pointers that are a small offset from NULL). And accessing memory that has not been mapped is an error. But there's no guarantees that accessing an invalid pointer will cause an error; this is why C and C++ are considered "unsafe" or "unmanaged" languages, while languages like Java or C# are considered "safe" or "managed" languages as they don't allow you to do this.

Comment: @Brian Again, I was just nitpicking, mainly because your original explanation lacked the sheer harshness of standardese. And seeing what your answer has become after a few edits (and I hope my nitpicking played a small role in that) I'm glad I did, because now it's **both** technically correct and newbie-friendly, best of both worlds. ;)

Comment: @syam Don't mind at all, and yes it did improve it. I was actually in the process of improving it already when you wrote the first comment, but I did realize that it had some more work to go after your comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Calling `ptr->method("2.5")` after `delete ptr` has [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). This means *anything* can happen, including what you're observing.

Answer (score 5):

In this code:

```
MyClass* ptr = new MyClass;
ptr->method("1");
delete ptr;
ptr->method("2.5");
```

you are accessing the memory that has already been freed, which yields ***undefined behavior***, which means that anything can happen including the worst case: that it seems to work correctly.

That's one of the reasons why it is a good practice to set such a pointer to `NULL` rather than allowing this kind of stuff happen:

```
delete ptr;
ptr = NULL;
```

although the best thing to do is to completely avoid using pointers if possible.

Answer (score 0):

you are accessing the memory, which is not reset until it is used by another new call or so.. however it is a good practice every time you call delete, is to set the pointer to `NULL`.