# C++ returning a pointer coming out of another function is copying it ? valgrind complains

Tags: c++, pointers, valgrind

sorry to post this, but i have not found any discussion dealing with the feeling i have when reading valgrind results. What i see is part of a large code, so i've tried to simplify it as much as possible.I have a class (ClassA), that contains a pointer to a object of another class (ClassB).  Both classes have a method named getArr that returns a double*. The one in ClassA basically returns a call to the one from ClassB through its pointer.
from what valgrind tells me, i've the feeling that ClassA is not really returning the pointer from its ClassB object but that it might copy it... Is is correct  and if so how to avoid it ?

here is the header:

```
class ClassB
{
 public:
   ClassB(){}
  ~ClassB(){}
  double *getArr();

};

class ClassA
{
 public:
  ClassA();
 ~ClassA();
 double *getArr();

  ClassB *myB;
 };
```

the functions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "OtherClasses.h"

using namespace std;

ClassA::ClassA()
{
  myB = new ClassB();
}

ClassA::~ClassA()
{
  if( myB )
delete myB;
}

double* ClassA::getArr()
{
  return (myB->getArr());
}

double* ClassB::getArr()
{
  double* arr = new double[10];
  for(unsigned int i=0; i<10; i++)
arr[i]=i;

  return arr;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  ClassA *myA = new ClassA();
  double* pouet = myA->getArr();

  for(unsigned int i=0; i<10; i++)
cout<<pouet[i]<<endl;

  delete[] pouet;
  if (myA)
delete myA;

}
```

and what is displayed:

```
==2115== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==2115== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==2115== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==2115== Command: ./bin/main
==2115== 
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
==2115== 
==2115== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2115==     in use at exit: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==2115==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 3 frees, 72,793 bytes allocated
==2115== 
==2115== 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==2115==    at 0x4A06C0F: malloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2115==    by 0x350388A1EF: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==2115==    by 0x34FD80F669: call_init.part.0 (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.21.so)
==2115==    by 0x34FD80F77A: _dl_init (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.21.so)
==2115==    by 0x34FD800CC9: ??? (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.21.so)
==2115== 
==2115== LEAK SUMMARY:
==2115==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2115==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2115==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2115==    still reachable: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==2115==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2115== 
==2115== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==2115== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

thanks in advance
jbb

EDIT: As said in the comments the behaviour described above is consistent with valgrind 3.10 and 3.11 and using g++ 5.1, 5.3 and clang++... The only compilator that gives 3 alloc and 3 frees (so no problem at all) is g++ 4.8

@Sarthak Singh: Removing the delete myB in ClassA destructor brings these line in the output of valgrind

```
==23329== 1 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 2
==23329==    at 0x4A07117: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==23329==    by 0x400A4C: ClassA::ClassA() (main.cpp:8)
==23329==    by 0x400B2E: main (main.cpp:34)
```

Comment: I am not seeing anything that should cause a memory leak here.  I would suggest switching to a `std::vector` if you want a array made at runtime.

Comment: It's unnecessary to check pointer before deleting it (like in  ~ClassA()). delete nullptr is a valid construction.

Comment: I'm just bothered by the 4 allocations and the 3 releasing of memory... the double pointer is just an simple example as in real i'm passing a more complex object. When automatically collecting memory issue through CDASH, it is one kind of complain that i'd like to see disappears. This is why i'm wondering whether there is sort of copy when transmitting the returned resulted pointer. Sorry if it's unclear and thanks

Comment: Interesting point: running with g++ 4.8.4, valgrind states that it all looks good (before it was with g++ 5.1.1): "All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible".  This is puzzling me a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems to me the leak is coming from libstdc++:

```
$> valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all ./a.out
[...]
==6664== 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==6664==    at 0x4C2ABD0: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6664==    by 0x4EBFE7F: pool (eh_alloc.cc:117)
==6664==    by 0x4EBFE7F: __static_initialization_and_destruction_0 (eh_alloc.cc:244)
==6664==    by 0x4EBFE7F: _GLOBAL__sub_I_eh_alloc.cc (eh_alloc.cc:307)
==6664==    by 0x400F3B9: call_init.part.0 (in /usr/lib/ld-2.23.so)
==6664==    by 0x400F4CA: _dl_init (in /usr/lib/ld-2.23.so)
==6664==    by 0x4000DC9: ??? (in /usr/lib/ld-2.23.so)
[...]
```

(which explains why the leak is only seen when using gcc-5.x)

it's either a real leak or some interplay b/w the libstdc++ version shipped with gcc-5.x and the hooks valgrind injects into the monitored process.

AFAIK, nothing much you can do about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the destructor of ClassB as `delete` just calls the destructor if it is defined.

You could read this for more info [Delete calling destructor but not deleting object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18990524/delete-calling-destructor-but-not-deleting-object)

Comment: As i thought, this bring another line in the valgrind output.  test

Comment: I've done test with g++ 5.3.1, valgrind 3.11 and clang++... it all results in the same issue... I really don't get why 4 allocations...  all ideas of tests are welcome.