# Why functions calls after delete?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to figure out how class pointers work, here example code:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
        void m(int x) {
                std::cout << "hello " << x << std::endl;
        }
};

int main() {

        A *a = new A();

        for (int i = 1; i < 9; ++i) { a->m(i); }

        delete a;

        a->m(123);

        return 0;

}
```

Why a->m(123); works after delete a;?

Comment: It's a manifestation of undefined behaviour, that's all. C++ gives you the ability to shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: I think, there should be crash, its worked for me as well.

Comment: @Mannoj: Says who? The C++ standard? You?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete calling destructor but not deleting object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18990524/delete-calling-destructor-but-not-deleting-object)

Comment: Because using a deleted pointer is [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). That means anything goes. Don't try to reason about whether it should crash or fail or work.

Comment: by pure chance, it is undefined behavior. @Mannoj, it is not necessary to crash. In release builds, this will usually work as if `a` was not deleted at all.

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic: "Usually"? Do you have statistical evidence to back this up?

Comment: Even the `std::cout << hello " << x << std::endl;` might be discarded.

Comment: @Jarod42: Some compilers will detect UB on the only control path and optimise to `int main(){}`

Comment: @Bathsheba, just a sec, I will do a scientific research to provide you with stats, be right back :) But yes, this exact program will usually work as if there is no huge bug in it.

Answer (score 3):

Accessing *memory/object* (through a pointer), which is *deleted/released/freed* is [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). You can not expect any reliable things to happen.

Comment: It is actually the object that is deleted not just the memory, ie the destructor is called.